# week number as column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

first of all my sql statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(
    SELECT SUM(Preis1)
    FROM tblBuchungsdaten
    WHERE (Datum BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -7, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) AND DATEADD(wk, -6, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))))
)AS '7 weeks ago',
(
    SELECT SUM(Preis1)
    FROM tblBuchungsdaten
    WHERE (Datum BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -6, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) AND DATEADD(wk, -5, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))))
)AS '6 weeks ago',
(
    SELECT SUM(Preis1)
    FROM tblBuchungsdaten
    WHERE (Datum BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -5, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) AND DATEADD(wk, -4, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))))
)AS '5 weeks ago',
(
    SELECT SUM(Preis1)
    FROM tblBuchungsdaten
    WHERE (Datum BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -4, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) AND DATEADD(wk, -3, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))))
)AS '4 weeks ago',
(
    SELECT SUM(Preis1)
    FROM tblBuchungsdaten
    WHERE (Datum BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -3, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) AND DATEADD(wk, -2, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))))
)AS '3 weeks ago',
(
    SELECT SUM(Preis1)
    FROM tblBuchungsdaten
    WHERE (Datum BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -2, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) AND DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))))
)AS '2 weeks ago',
(
    SELECT SUM(Preis1)
    FROM tblBuchungsdaten
    WHERE (Datum BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) AND DATEADD(wk, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))))
)AS '1 week ago'
FROM tblBuchungsdaten;
```

It creates this output:
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7j3t.png)
That far I´m happy with the results, but I would love now having the week number of each sub select as column name.

The output should look like this:
[needed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKuwq.png)

Comment: You can only have dynamic names with dynamic SQL; It's unlikely you really want to go down that path. *Also, this looks a lot like the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64158951/2029983). Perhaps you have [Celvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9722404/celvin) might be worth talking about ideas with each other, as seems like the same project.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your existing query, you can change to use `CASE` statement or `PIVOT`

example below uses the `CASE` statement

```
SELECT  SUM (CASE WHEN Datum BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -7, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) 
                             AND     DATEADD(wk, -6, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) 
          THEN Preis1
          END) as '7 weeks ago',
        SUM (CASE WHEN Datum BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -6, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) 
                             AND     DATEADD(wk, -5, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) 
          THEN Preis1
          END) as '6 weeks ago',
        . . . . .
FROM    tblBuchungsdaten
```

And to have the week number as column name, you need to use `Dynamic SQL`. Check out [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)